# Android: How to update visibility of views in Custom Listview Item

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a Custom Listview with a checkbox and TextView in each Item. Initially I set the visibility of checkbox to GONE.

In my activity on clicking a button, checkboxes in all the items appear and again on clicking all checkboxes disappear(acts like a toggle button).

I had successfully implemented with a small problem :

[image]

Here, in the 1st pic, when I click toggle button,checkboxes did not appear. They are appearing only when I scroll(2nd pic). Upon clicking button, items in the current view are not updating its visibility as getView will be called ONLY when we scroll.

I just want to remove the checkboxes in the current view too upon button click.

Here is my code :

```
public View getView(final int index, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   final ViewHolder holder;
   ...
   ...
   if(myActivity.buttonFlag)
      holder.myCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   else
      holder.myCheckBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   return convertView;
   }
static class ViewHolder
{
    CheckBox myCheckBox;
}
```

`buttonFlag` is a boolean which set its value true/false on a button click. Button click and `buttonFlag` value is set in the Activity.

Comment: Could You provide code for toggle button handling? Are You calling notifyDataSetChanged() when it toggles?

Comment: Great! Its working now. I thought notifyDataSetChanged() works only if items are added/deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems calling to `notifyDataSetChanged()` should be done from toggle button handler in order to make list refresh its contents.